# PHP 7 can not handle exception in mapping explode result to a list

Tags: php, date, parsing, exception

I am parsing user-entered date of birth, users enter birth in random formats.
Previously I handled it using exception, but after upgrading to PHP, PHP doesn't handle exceptions and app crashes and does not call showError and throws **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in** :

```
try {
    $birth="1980";
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("/", $birth);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    showError("Error in date format");
}
```

Comment: It **hasn't** been throwing an exception ever since it existed.

Comment: Agree, notice is not an exception.

Answer (score 4):

Do not explode to a list. Explode to an array first, and then deconstruct if count matches.

```php
try
{
    $birth="1980";
    $data = explode("/", $birth);
    if(count($data) === 3) {
        list($year, $month, $day) = $data;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Error in Date format');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    showError($e->getMessage());
}
```

---

## EDIT

As commenter [EL_Vanja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4205384/el-vanja) suggested, there is really no need for working with exceptions in this case. I would also recommend using the short way like this:

```php
$birth="1980";
$data = explode("/", $birth);
if(count($data) === 3) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = $data;
} else {
    showError('Error in Date format');
}
```

Comment: No need for exception anymore, though. It could just be `showError` in the `else` branch.

Comment: Sure, but you can refine it for more exeptions of different types. Like "day out of range". Depending on flow, maybe the exception should not be catched or thrown at all.

Comment: Yeah, but you can also refine it directly. I don't see what the Exception is adding to the mechanism, there's no logging.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Wouldn't have used Exceptions for my own, but I wanted to keep the code "intact" and updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I often do that myself. Just wanted to comment for anyone reading this in the future.